# The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" reported an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, mysql-5.1

I created a linked server to MySQL database server on my SQL Server database server. I tested the connection. It succeeded successfully for MySQL connection. I can see the databases on MySQL instance via my linked server but when i try to run a query with OPENROWSET, it gives me an error message like below. I have searched it on google many times but i couldn't solve my issue. What is the problem? Why do i get this message and how to solve it?

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure. Msg
>   7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 25 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue once, You may need to recreate the linked server with this set to **false** (or just change it in the linked server properties->server options):

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'servername', 
    @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

Additionally, try using [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) to run this against the link

syntax:

```
OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )
```

and example SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(server_name,'SELECT * FROM table_name');
```

Comment: Unfourtunately, i got the error message below : 

** The OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)". **

Comment: What is the catastrophic failure? :/ 

The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.